# (Solved) PDF show blank page in adobe acrobat

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf, pdf-reader

Hello im using dompdf to convert html into pdf in codeigniter 3, when i download pdf and open in pdf reader browser the pdf is shown.

[pdf In browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYVOz.png)

But when i open pdf in adobe acrobat the pdf just show blank page
[pdf in adobe acrobat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAHxc.png)

This is my code:

```
$html = $this->load->view('viewhtml', $data, TRUE);
//echo $html;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);


// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->getCanvas()->get_cpdf()->setEncryption("1234");

        // Output the generated PDF to Browser

$dompdf->stream("name.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));


exit(0);
```

I don't know what is wrong can someone help me.

EDIT: when I open pdf in different pdf reader, the pdf is shown

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB9du.png)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dE7Rdjv-KWCumj6MOAxereM7mmG3XwnX/view?usp=share_link

This is my pdf file if you want to see it in adobe acrobat. (pass: 1234)

Comment: Another possibility is a syntax error in the PDF which is ignored by some readers.

Comment: Without the actual PDF this is hard to tell.

Comment: when i use $dompdf->getCanvas()->get_cpdf()->setEncryption("1234"); i get that error, but when i comment the $dompdf->getCanvas()->get_cpdf()->setEncryption("1234"); and download it and open in adobe acrobat the pdf is show

Comment: and i open the pdf in different pdf reader instead adobe acrobat the pdf is show

Comment: i just edit the answer

Comment: i upload in g drive, but when i open it the text is show, just in adobe acrobat the pdf is corrupt, how do i share it?

Comment: Or you want to download it and open in acrobat?

Comment: i just edit my question

Comment: Why are you still using version 0.8.3, which was released 5 years ago and contains issues like [this one](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/2060)?

Comment: Sorry, i cant update it because the project is use php ver 5

Comment: Yes my issue is just like that you share

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting the provided example PDF one sees that the **CIDSystemInfo** entry for the *DejaVuSans* font embedded in the file is broken:

```
11 0 obj
<</Registry ‘7_wá
/Ordering ‘#x.<
/Supplement 0
>>
```

The values of **Registry** and **Ordering** should have been strings but here they are completely broken (even in an encrypted document strings have to be properly delimited).

This error has been fixed in the dompdf pull request [2114](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/pull/2114) in March 2020 which indeed is the fix for the dompdf issue [2060](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/2060) pointed out by @Olivier in a comment to your question.

Thus, please update your dompdf version to a state that includes the above-mentioned pull request.

Comment: So, the solution is update the dompdf version?

Comment: Is there any other solution because i cant update it

Comment: @namarahasia Just manually apply the [changes](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/pull/2114/files) of the pull request.

Comment: OMG, it works, thank you so much.